# Pgadmin4 doesn't start with WSL Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pgadmin, wsl-2, pgadmin-4

I installed pgadmin on my Ubuntu 22.04.3 WSL following the official documentation.

```
curl -fsS https://www.pgadmin.org/static/packages_pgadmin_org.pub | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/packages-pgadmin-org.gpg

sudo sh -c 'echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/packages-pgadmin-org.gpg] https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/pgadmin/pgadmin4/apt/$(lsb_release -cs) pgadmin4 main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgadmin4.list && apt update'

sudo apt install pgadmin4
```

When I want to launch the software with "pgadmin4" I end up with the error "pgadmin4: command not found".

So the software is installed, but I can't launch it, do you have any ideas?

I checked if the installation was good with "apt list --installed":

```
pgadmin4-desktop/pgadmin4,now 8.2 amd64 [installed]
pgadmin4-server/pgadmin4,now 8.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
pgadmin4-web/pgadmin4,now 8.2 all [installed,auto-removable]
```

Answer (score 0):

For pgadmin4-desktop you can find the binary in:
`/usr/pgadmin4/bin/pgadmin4` and run that. I assume that is what you are looking for?

For pgadmin4-server there is /usr/pgadmin4/venv/bin which contains some applications. Not sure what your are looking for in this case.

Comment: It's exactly what I'm looking for, the executable in /usr/pgadmin4/bin/pgadmin4, but in this /bin directory, I can't find pgadmin4. Additionally, when I try to run "pgadmin4" in my terminal, I get the error "command not found".

Comment: Can't you just run the executable from there? Or is the executable missing? If it's there you might be able to add `/usr/pgadmin4/bin/` to your path. `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/pgadmin4/bin/"`. That way it should start by typing `pgadmin4`.

Comment: Thank's ! It's works with your solution to add /usr/pgadmin4/bin/ to my path export PATH="$PATH:/usr/pgadmin4/bin/".